# vectorized quadratic formula, why is the runtime warning invalid value in numpy.sqrt() still raised?

Tags: python, numpy

numpy version 1.20.1

Bob lawblaw's Law Blog, I need more details, this post has tooooo much code.

```
def quadratic_formula(a, b, c):
    """just like the song

    Args:
        a (numpy.ndarray): shape(N,1)
        b (numpy.ndarray): shape(N,1)
        c (numpy.ndarray): shape(N,1)

    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: shape(N,2)
        * [soln_a, soln_b]
        * [np.NaN, np.NaN] when discriminant is negative
        * [soln_a, soln_a] single soln when discriminate == 0]
       
    Notes: 
    .. math::
        ax^2 + bx + c = 0
        solns = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}

    """
    # TODO: raise value error if any a == 0


    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    c = np.array(c)

    det = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c

    res_a = np.where(
        det >= 0, 
        (-b + np.sqrt(det)) / (2 * a),
        np.NaN,
       )

    res_b = np.where(
        det >= 0, 
        (-b - np.sqrt(det)) / (2 * a),
        np.NaN,
    )
    
    res = np.array([res_a, res_b]).T

    return res
```

```
a = [1,2]
b = [1,0]
c = [0,1]

res = quadratic_formula(a,b,c)
print(res)
```

```
>>> [[0, -1],
     [NaN, NaN]]
```

works, but raise `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt`.

Why is the square root even evaluated for a negative discriminant?
Any suggestions for implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are still computing `np.sqrt(det)` for all values of `det` hence the warning. The where filters the x and y arrays *after* they have been computed.

The implementation can be fixed by simply casting the a,b and c arrays to complex.

```
    a = np.array(a).astype(complex)
    b = np.array(b).astype(complex)
    c = np.array(c).astype(complex)
```

That way numpy knows to use the complex version of sqrt. Once you are there you can completely omit the np.where and check after the fact if your solutions are real, if that is what you are interested on only.